# How to fetch the JSON array values with condition when we do not have key-value pair

Tags: performance-testing

```
    {
  "Data": {
    "pData": [
      {
        "label": "A",
        "value": "1",
        "data": [
          "S_1",
          "OB_1",
          "1.21",
          "2.00",
          "2.17",
          "199",
          "2",
          "96032",
          "687"
        ],
        "uom": null
      },
      {
        "label": "b",
        "value": "16",
        "data": [
          "S_5",
          "OB",
          "767",
          "120.00",
          "90.83",
          "0",
          "2",
          "960300",
          "687"
        ],
        "uom": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "Status": true,
  "Message": "Success"
}
```

**1 I would like to take the values $..data[3] only if $..data[6] is not equal to zero,Please help me with the expression
2 I would like to fetch $..data[*].value only if$..data[6] is not equal to zero **

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), the relevant [Json Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression would be something like:

```
$.Data.pData[?(@.data[6] == '0')].data[3]
```

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T,It resolved my issue.